# Use Members of One Class in Another Class (OOP)

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

I have two classes Instructor and Game.

Instructor.h

```
class Instructor
{
    int instrID;

public:
    Instructor();
    void showGameStatus();
    int createGame();                           
    vector<int> createGames(int numberOfGames); 
};
```

Game.h:

```
class Game {

private:                            
    int gID;                        
    int instrID;                    
    int pFactID;                    
public:

    Game() {                // default constructor
        gID = 0;
        instrID = 0;
        pFactID = 0;

    };
```

These are in Instructor.cpp

```
void Instructor::showGameStatus()
{

}

int Instructor::createGame()
{
    Game g;
}
```

CreateGame() initializes a game. I want that upon calling showGameStatus() I can print out all properties (eg gId, InstrId) of the Game g that initialized earlier etc.

Is it possible to access the properties of Game g that in another method?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Class Instructor should inherit class Game:
class Instructor::public Game{
*your code here*
}

Comment: Inheritance forms no part of a proper OO solution to this question. Instructors aren't games, or *vice versa.*

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: No.

The longer answer is this: If I understand correctly, what you want to accomplish, the problem is that the object `g` of type `Game` is held by a local variable inside the scope of your `Instructor::createGame` member function. Once that function is "done", i.e. the local scope ends, the object, which has **[automatic storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)** will be destroyed. It's gone. I don't know what the `int` means that you return, but no matter what it does, it doesn't hold an object of type `Game`.

Now, you *probably* want your `createGame` to return some type of handle to an actual `Game` object. Depending on your specific setting, *it is your job to choose how to pass such an object around*. For example, one way might be this:

```
Game Instructor::createGame() const { // 1
  Game g;
  // do stuff with g, perhaps?
  return g;
}
```

Another might be:

```
std::unique_ptr<Game> Instructor::createGame() const { // 2
  auto gptr = std::make_unique<Game>();
  // do stuff with gptr, perhaps?
  return gptr;
}
```

Or yet another:

```
std::size_t Instructor::createGame() { // 3
  // Instructor has a member std::vector<Game> games
  games.emplace_back();
  // do stuff with games.back()
  return games.size()-1;
}
```

There are countless other ways to pass the object around.

No matter what you choose you *have* to pass **something** to identify **which** `Game` object you are talking about back into your `showGameStatus` function, if you plan to have more than one `Game` object flying around (I assume you do).

```
auto some_handle = instructor.createGame();
// ... later ...
instructor.showGameStatus(some_handle);
```

---

This all holds true, *if you want more than one object*. **Otherwise** you might want to just add the object as a member of your `Instructor` type:

```
class Instructor {
  private:
    Game game;
  public:
    Instructor() : game() {}
    // no createGame function, it is superfluous
    void showGameStatus() const {
      game.some_output_function();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just inherit the Instructor Class into the Game Class and do your work...

Comment: Your solution is applicable to the question, but you should specify how and make changes to the given code / some parts of it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'inherit into'? Inheritance forms no part of a proper OO solution to this question. Instructors aren't games, or *vice versa.*